# Does 住 人 mean "people living in the area" or "real live people, as opposed to puppets and fictions"?

Tags: usage

I see various written sentences that refer to 住 人 .

The dictionary says this means "living people," but 住 seems to be "live" in the sense of "I live in Beijing," or "I reside in Beijing."

So if the sentence says "There are 住 人  here," does that mean, "There are people who reside in this area," or "There are living people here, but in the other room there are only non-living things such as puppets"?

Thanks.

Edit:

Okay, when I originally posted the question, I saw the characters on  banner ad and didn't bother clicking the ad.

Since that time, I found another copy of the banner ad and noticed that they used more than a few Japanese characters.  I clicked through and found the game that the original ad was advertising.  It seems to be "Inhabitant Love" which makes no sense to me.  It seems to be hosted in Taiwan, so the major language of the site should be Mandarin.

I am putting a link to an imgur screencap.  I think the red-outlined slogan is "Which one do you want to choose (選擇) today?"  I think the yellow text says "Just want to be with you."

This makes little sense to me.  I understand that dating sims involve characters, but why call them "inhabitants"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3kLy.jpg

Second Edit:

[http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/detail/主人/1319943](http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/detail/%E4%B8%BB%E4%BA%BA/1319943)

Wait a minute.  I misread the characters.  It isn't "Inhabitant People Love," it's "mistress love."  Or possibly "master love," as in, the player gets to be the master of a household and the maids are his romantic conquests.

I need to recognize what's actually written, not what I'm looking for.  I had been studying different characters and I saw the characters I was looking for, not what was actually written. Sorry about that.

Comment: 这里住人 definitely means 这里有 人居住的踪迹。(There is a sign that people are living here) If only animals live in some place, you know, it is always distinguishable. Animals don't clean the room, or put things in order. It is perhaps that the house master is out for a while and visitors only see puppets, but it doesn't mean there is nobody living here.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

哈哈, 主人 and 住人. 主人 means master or m'lord. 住人 means a building can have residence.

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you provided the sentence in question.

Baidu (http://baike.baidu.com/view/1402096.htm) gives two definitions for 住人 as a noun, meaning either residents or, in the right construction, a group of people demarcated by the preceding description

ABC has 住人 as a separable verb meaning to "accommodate or put up people"

现代汉语词典 doesn't list 住人

And since 住 is a common complement, it could be that 人 is the object of V+住

It could also appear in 同住人, meaning husband and wife, and in 常住人口, meaning permanent residents

Comment: I found the relevant ad and clicked it.  I had hesitated to click it before because I wasn't sure whether it would start geo-locating my IP address and start advertising "people living in my neighborhood."

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, this is verb-subject structure upside-down, just like sometimes in English:

There **lives** a man in a house. (A normal English sentence: A man lives in a house).

So you can think:

一个人住房子里。

房子里住人。（similar to "There + verb + subject……"）

Sometimes, "住人" also means **whether a place suitable for living**：

这里合适**住人**吗？(Is this place suitable for living?)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the previous answers, 住人 seems to be (at least in my experience) used more or less as a combination of verb and noun. Thus, your first definition - "people living in the area" - seems correct (at least in the sense of "residents").

The second usage you suggested seems to be incorrect - 住, as far as I understand it, means "to live [in/at/etc.]" in the sense of residence, rather than in a biological sense of "to live". You *could* have something such as "这层楼住人", but this only implies that the other building(s) are for a different purpose other than housing people.